# How can I test the two parameter estimates in the different model?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I want to test the two parameter estimates in the different model.
First model:
\begin{equation}
Y_{t,USGDP}=\beta_{0,US}+\beta_{1,US}\times X_{t,USconsumption}+u_{t,US}
\end{equation}

Second model:
\begin{equation}
Y_{t,JapanGDP}=\beta_{0,Japan}+\beta_{1,Japan}\times X_{t,Japanconsumption}+u_{t,Japan}
\end{equation}

where $t$ denotes a time, $Y$ is a dependent variable, $X$ is a dependent variable, $u$ is an error term. Ignore the unit root process in the model here.

Here, I want to test $\beta_{1,US}=\beta_{1,Japan}$.

Please teach me the methodology of the test.

Answer (score 1):

(I’m going to ignore the time component and leave it to you to handle, for instance, an autoregressive error term when you do inference.)

A typical way to test this is with an interaction term between the $X$ variable and an indicator variable about the country.

Instead of having two regression models,

$$\text{(Japan) } y= \alpha_0+\alpha_1X+\epsilon\\
\text{(US) }y=\beta_0+\beta_1X+\epsilon
$$

Use one regression model with $Z$ as an indicator variable for the country.

$$
Y=\gamma_0+\gamma_1X+\gamma_2Z+\gamma_3XZ+\epsilon
$$

In this setup, $\gamma_2$ is the difference between the intercepts for each country, and $\gamma_3$ is the difference between the slopes for each country, both of which you can formally test.